# Set a textarea to auto size relative to content on load before user modifies content

Tags: javascript

JS newbie here.

html/php:

```
<textarea style="width: 260px; height: 120px; min-height: 120px;" id="txt1" name="txt1" oninput="txrz('txt1')" data-resizable="true" maxlength="500" required><?=$res[0]['txt1']?></textarea>
```

js:

```
function txrz(id) {
    let a = document.getElementById(id);
    a.style.height = 'auto';
    a.style.height = (a.scrollHeight+40)+'px';
}

function init() {
    let a = document.querySelectorAll('[data-resizable="true"]');   //Get the textarea(s) we want to resize

    for(let i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        let id = a[i].id;   //Gets the respective id(s)
        let txt = a[i].value;   //Not really necessary but used to see the script can register content is present
        txrz(id);   //Run the function we want

        console.log(id + ' contains: ' + txt);

    }
}
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

I am trying to get many of the textarea fields in a form to auto resize based on what is put into them. This seems to work fine with the `txrz` function. The only problem I am having is that often a form is saved with data in it, then when the user returns to the form the textarea size loads to the css default irrespective of holding content in the value field or not. It triggers correctly as soon as the user types a character into the field or removes one out. I am attempting to get the function to fire on page load so each textarea appears at it's set min-height if empty or correctly extended per content if it is not empty. However despite not throwing any errors, my `init` function is not doing it's job, despite several variation attempts.

Other (perhaps) useful info:
There are more than one textarea fields per page which this solution needs to work for. 
CSS hides the scrollbar and lower right drag resizer of the textarea appropriately.
No jQuery or other library is being used. I strictly need to make this work vanilla style.

Can someone please explain to me why this is not working and advise on how to make it function as desired?

TIA

Comment: How do you load the default value? I created a codepen with a default value, and that works for me. How is it different from your code?

https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/QWjRBPz?editors=1011

Comment: @Gh05d Hello - when you ask "How do you load the default value?" I am assuming you mean the value that is placed into my example above by php. This comes out of a mysql database and was saved there by the user from a previous visit to this form. I'm unsure as to why this does not appear to work on Chrome Version 81.0.4044.138 (Official Build) (64-bit). Your codepen DOES work though. I have no idea why. Perhaps something to do with codepen using/referencing Babel?

Comment: Ok, I think I was not clear enough. To simulate the "default" value, I added in the second textarea in my codepen a text between ```<textarea></textarea>```, so for example like this ```<textarea>Hello World</textarea>```. Do you do it the same way with the data from the database or do you pass it as a property or load it into it on page load?

Comment: @Gh05d It's done the same way - the php throws the text content from the database between the `<teatarea></textarea>` tags server side before throwing it at the users browser, so it **should** be working exactly as your codepen - which is exactly the original intended way it's supposed to work. I've no idea why it's not. Tested in Chrome and Firefox both with same failure.

Comment: Ok, but in my codepen (on firefox and chromium) it works. When there is too much text, then textbox grows. Do you have maybe any addblocker, script blocker or something else installed? Do you have another laptop to test the pen?

Comment: @Gh05d Yes your codepen works for me as well, just my dev project doesn't. I'm not using anything additional at all - all other JS functions on this project work perfectly. I'm building it on a VM and have just tested it on an iPad with precisely the same failure. Is it possible your codepen is using something additional that I'm not? I see a reference in the JS box to Babel which is something I am not using/don't have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214754/discussion-between-dan-francis-and-gh05d).

Comment: Sorry, can only drop in and off here, so won't make it now to the chat, maybe later. You would need Babel for new Javascript features like arrow functions and const / let variables. Your code looks pretty vanilla to me, so I don't think that this is the issue.

Comment: @Gh05d No problem, thanks for taking a look. Code is intended to be pure vanilla - I have just tried changing my `let`s to `var`s as a bit of a desperate attempt to make a difference - no success.